# How to print "\r" to a file

Tags: c, printf, carriage-return

I want to show a progress bar in my program so I add this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    puts("begin");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d%% finished.\r", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(100000);
    }
    puts("end");
}
```

when it outputs to `stdout` it shows nicely a line indicating the current progress.

However if I direct its output to a file, then all the lines with `printf("%d%% finished.\r", i);` are missing.

Is it possible to keep all the lines in a file?

Comment: I have a feeling that all the lines *are* in the file. Take a look at the file size in bytes, or look at the file with a hex editor.

Comment: @user3386109 wow the lines are indeed in the file! It just appears to be missing when i simply `cat` or `wc -l` the file. Could you kindly please make your comment an answer so I could accept it? Thanks

Comment: I'll let @SomeProgrammerDude add it to his answer, since his answer has some additional useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the lines be missing in your output file, but it is possible that copying the file to the terminal occurs so quickly that each line overwrites the previous one without a chance for you to see it. Unlike your program, `cat` will not pause between the lines. Only the last line will be visible at the end, if it is at least as long as the previous ones.

Dump the file in hexadecimal with `od -x` to check the actual file contents.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really use formatting like that when output is redirected to a file, because output to the file only writes forward, it never writes backwards.

If you're on a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) then you can use [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) to detect if your writing to an actual terminal or not, and change your output formatting accordingly.